# Exception while execution of mule expression

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I have written below expression that caused ExpressionRuntimeException.

Is there anything wrong with this piece of code? 
Note: This code failed only once out of many runs.

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[
flowVars['flowType'] = "CacheServicePageData";
flowVars['recordKey']=com.xyz.connect.util.ConnectRedisUtil.buildAndReturnREDISCacheKey(sessionVars.cdmID, payload.pageNumber);
flowVars['pageNumber']=payload.pageNumber;
flowVars['pageSize']=payload.pageSize;]]>
</expression-component>
```

com.xyz.connect.util.ConnectRedisUtil.buildAndReturnREDISCacheKey():

public static String buildAndReturnREDISCacheKey(String transactionID, Integer pageNumber) {
        return new StringBuilder(transactionID).append(":").append(Constant.REDIS_BATCH_PAGE_HASH_STRING).append(pageNumber).toString();
    }

I found following logs:

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "
flowVars['flowType'] = "CacheServicePageData";
flowVars['recordKey']=com.xyz.connect.util.ConnectRedisUtil.buildAndReturnREDISCacheKey(sessionVars.cdmID, payload.pageNumber);
flowVars['pageNumber']=payload.pageNumber;
flowVars['pageSize']=payload.pageSize;" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).
Element               : /payroll-cdm-process-page/processors/1 @ connect-cdm-core-settlement-id:payroll-cdm-batch.xml:429 (Expression)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
Execution of the expression "
flowVars['flowType'] = "CacheServicePageData";
flowVars['recordKey']=com.xyz.connect.util.ConnectRedisUtil.buildAndReturnREDISCacheKey(sessionVars.cdmID, payload.pageNumber);
flowVars['pageNumber']=payload.pageNumber;
flowVars['pageSize']=payload.pageSize;" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.mvel2.ParserContext.getVariableScope(ParserContext.java:706)
  org.mule.mvel2.ParserContext.initializeTables(ParserContext.java:445)
  org.mule.mvel2.compiler.ExpressionCompiler._compile(ExpressionCompiler.java:124)
  org.mule.mvel2.compiler.ExpressionCompiler.compile(ExpressionCompiler.java:63)
  org.mule.mvel2.MVEL.analysisCompile(MVEL.java:681)
  org.mule.mvel2.MVEL.analysisCompile(MVEL.java:685)
  org.mule.mvel2.compiler.PropertyVerifier.getCollectionProperty(PropertyVerifier.java:443)
  org.mule.mvel2.compiler.PropertyVerifier.analyze(PropertyVerifier.java:126)
  org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.optimizeSetAccessor(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:278)
  org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledAccExpression.setValue(CompiledAccExpression.java:68)
  org.mule.mvel2.ast.AssignmentNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(AssignmentNode.java:111)
  org.mule.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:86)
  org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123)
  org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119)
  org.mule.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:953)


Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.Exception: org.mule.api.MessagingException: Execution of the expression "
flowVars['flowType'] = "CacheServicePageData";
flowVars['recordKey']=com.xyz.connect.util.ConnectRedisUtil.buildAndReturnREDISCacheKey(sessionVars.cdmID, payload.pageNumber);
flowVars['pageNumber']=payload.pageNumber;
flowVars['pageSize']=payload.pageSize;" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:326) ~[groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:44) ~[groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar:2.4.4]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.mule.module.scripting.component.Scriptable.runScript(Scriptable.java:372) ~[mule-module-scripting-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.scripting.component.ScriptComponent.doInvoke(ScriptComponent.java:78) ~[mule-module-scripting-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:120) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.mule.api.MessagingException: Execution of the expression "
flowVars['flowType'] = "CacheServicePageData";
flowVars['recordKey']=com.xyz.connect.util.ConnectRedisUtil.buildAndReturnREDISCacheKey(sessionVars.cdmID, payload.pageNumber);
flowVars['pageNumber']=payload.pageNumber;
flowVars['pageSize']=payload.pageSize;" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80) ~[groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105) ~[groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60) ~[groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235) ~[groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247) ~[groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar:2.4.4]
    at Script175.run(Script175.groovy:1) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:323) ~[groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:44) ~[groovy-all-2.4.4-indy.jar:2.4.4]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.mule.module.scripting.component.Scriptable.runScript(Scriptable.java:372) ~[mule-module-scripting-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.scripting.component.ScriptComponent.doInvoke(ScriptComponent.java:78) ~[mule-module-scripting-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:120) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.MessagingException: Execution of the expression "
flowVars['flowType'] = "CacheServicePageData";
flowVars['recordKey']=com.xyz.connect.util.ConnectRedisUtil.buildAndReturnREDISCacheKey(sessionVars.cdmID, payload.pageNumber);
flowVars['pageNumber']=payload.pageNumber;
flowVars['pageSize']=payload.pageSize;" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:42) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$2.process(Flow.java:138) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.construct.Flow$2.process(Flow.java:133) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: Execution of the expression "
flowVars['flowType'] = "CacheServicePageData";
flowVars['recordKey']=com.xyz.connect.util.ConnectRedisUtil.buildAndReturnREDISCacheKey(sessionVars.cdmID, payload.pageNumber);
flowVars['pageNumber']=payload.pageNumber;
flowVars['pageSize']=payload.pageSize;" failed.
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluateInternal(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:232) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:163) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:142) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.el.ExpressionLanguageComponent.process(ExpressionLanguageComponent.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: no context
    at org.mule.mvel2.ParserContext.getVariableScope(ParserContext.java:706) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.ParserContext.initializeTables(ParserContext.java:445) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.ExpressionCompiler._compile(ExpressionCompiler.java:124) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.ExpressionCompiler.compile(ExpressionCompiler.java:63) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.MVEL.analysisCompile(MVEL.java:681) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.MVEL.analysisCompile(MVEL.java:685) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.PropertyVerifier.getCollectionProperty(PropertyVerifier.java:443) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.PropertyVerifier.analyze(PropertyVerifier.java:126) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.optimizeSetAccessor(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:278) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledAccExpression.setValue(CompiledAccExpression.java:68) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.ast.AssignmentNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(AssignmentNode.java:111) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:86) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:953) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-012.jar:?]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionExecutor.execute(MVELExpressionExecutor.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluateInternal(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:228) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:163) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:142) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.el.ExpressionLanguageComponent.process(ExpressionLanguageComponent.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27) ~[mule-core-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no more lines in the error stack trace? More line could include a root cause that would be useful to identify the issue. What Mule version exactly is this?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Runtime is 3.8.5, found some more logs, please see the updated case.

Comment: Is that a single stack trace or is it several errors appended together? It doesn't make sense that there are mixed Expression component traces and Scripting component traces mixed together.

Comment: Also, is there any other Java component, custom transformer etc executed previous to this error?

Comment: @aled I combined two different exception stack traces, and also removed some lines because of limitation on number of characters allowed by stackoverflow.

Comment: @aled regarding java component, no we are not executing any transformer before executing that expression

Comment: I understand the intention of providing more information, however mixing different stacktrace from different instances or errors add confusion. Ideally you should add all lines from each and separate both clearly. I'm not able to say if the removed lines are relevant or not. It looks like at some point you tried to replace the expression component with the scripting component, which makes sense as an alternative, but I'm not able to see what the root cause of the scripting component was. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

There is some very unusual error going on that causes the "no context" error. I would try to use a separate  assignment for each flowVar, to see better which one is failing.

Something executing previously in Java could be breaking the execution context. Review all Java code usage executed previously.

There could be some issue related to MEL fixed in a later version. Currently the last Mule 3.x version is 3.9.4. It may or not help, but at least all known issues in previous versions will be fixed.

Another alternative is to use the scripting component, which from some of the stack traces you already tried. It is not clear what was the result.